# Get MongoDB documents where all subdocuments match criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm `Mongo` newbie, so this may be a trivial question. Please bear with me :)

My `Mongo` documents can be logically grouped to *valid* and *archive* documents. Document is valid, if **any** of its `revisions.validTo` date field is either `null` or greater than today. Otherwise, document is in archive.

So the collection structure is roughly:

```
[
    {
        _id: 'valid-1',
        info: 'This is valid document because it has a revision with null validTo value',
        revisions: [
            {
                validTo: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            },
            {
                validTo: null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 'valid-2',
        info: 'This is valid document because it has a revision with validTo value > today',
        revisions: [
            {
                validTo: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            },
            {
                validTo: ISODate("2050-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: 'archive-1',
        info: 'This document is in archive as all revisions have validTo < today',
        revisions: [
            {
                validTo: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can easily query the valid documents with

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({
  $or: [
    { 'revisions.validTo': { $gte: new Date() } },
    { 'revisions.validTo': null }
  ]
})
```

which returns `[valid-1, valid-2]`, but I can't find out how to query for the archive documents to get result `[archive-1]`. For example

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({
  'revisions.validTo': { $lte: new Date() }
})
```

returns a document if it has any revision with `validTo` < today. Instead of that I would like to get document only if **all** of its `revisions.validTo` are < today.

As the collection is exactly divided to these two groups, I could probably also get the archive group by querying the valid group and then taking difference between whole collection and valid documents set. This could maybe be done with Mongo aggregation framework, but I couldn't find out how to do that yet.

So, any help with constructing the archive documents query is warmly welcome!

(I'm also using Mongoose, if that could help somehow..?)

Comment: Your `validTo` shoud be an ISO date. Also what is your expected result?

Comment: I edited the example collection to use `ISODate`s. Also added a bit more explanation about expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with `$and`, `$not` and `$ne` operators as below,

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({
  $and: [
    { 'revisions.validTo': { $lte: new Date() } },
    { 'revisions.validTo': { $not: { $gte: new Date() } } },
    { 'revisions.validTo': { $ne: null } }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Actually it seems that the `$lte` criteria is not even needed. The trick was to state that no `revisions.validTo` can be greater than today. I can't believe how long it took to wrap my head around this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to re-model you're document so that the dates are ISODates so you can query operations on them

```
[
    {
        info: 'This is valid document because it has a revision with null validTo value',
        revisions: [
            {
                validTo: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            },
            {
                validTo: null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        info: 'This document is in archive as all revisions have validTo < today',
        revisions: [
            {
                validTo: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then you can use the following query:

```
db.docs.find({ 'revisions.validTo': { $lte: new Date() }, 'revisions.validTo': { $ne: null } } ).pretty()
```

To return

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584a9a9212767a1fecf0e39f"),
        "info" : "This document is in archive as all revisions have validTo < today",
        "revisions" : [
                {
                        "validTo" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! Unfortunately this approach does not seem to work. If I understood correctly, when using the same object key (`revisions.validTo`) several times, only the last criteria is actually used. So one should either use `$and: [...]` or implicit `$and` with `revisions.validTo: { $ne: null, $not: { $gt: new Date() } }`.